# How do I Generate a Certificate Signing Request?

Tags: xcode, macos, certificate, key-generator

Every time I try to generate a certificate, I get this error. I have restarted the computer and it is still happening. I have no ideas what to do.

I'm running MacOS 10.15.5 on a 5k iMac. I have never had this issue before.

[image]

Comment: Did you check [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302866/keychain-access-error-when-creating-new-system-certificate/304008#304008) or  [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309017/unknown-error-2-147-414-007-on-creating-certificate-with-certificate-assist) thread?

Comment: @omerfarukozturk I'm glad I tried to solve it myself first, because my answer solved it.

Answer (score 0):

In the Keychain Access window, make sure you don't have any of the private keys selected. I'm not sure what the interaction is, but it changes what you are requesting from the authority as you can see by the menu text changing:

[image]
[image]